# Comment « falloir » sémantiquement glisse de 'manquer' à 'avoir besoin de'?

Tags: étymologie

Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « le manquement » avec « [le besoin, la nécessité](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/falloir) » ? Ces notions ne se lient pas externement !

Par exemple :

- une bagnole me manque mais je ne la requiers, car je suis aveugle ou je hais conduire !
- la livre me manque mais je ne la requiers, car je n'habite pas ou je hais visiter le Royaume Uni.

[Peu s'en faut - PARLER FRANÇAIS](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/peu-s-en-faut-a147253824)

> À l'origine (XIe siècle) était le verbe ***faillir*** (d'abord *falir* ou *fallir*), emprunté du latin populaire *fallire*, lui-même issu du latin classique *fallere* (« tromper, échapper à, manquer à [sa parole] »). Sa conjugaison hésitait entre les formes en *fal-* et celles en *faill-* : (indicatif présent) *il falt* (puis *fault, faut*) ; (passé simple) *il fali* (ou *failli, faillit*) ; (futur) *il faldra* (puis *faudra* ou *faillira*) ; etc. ***Falloir***, quant à lui, n'est autre que la réfection de ***faillir*** (pris au sens de « faire défaut, manquer ») sur le modèle de *valoir* (d'après *il faut/il vaut, il faudra/il vaudra*) : « Conjugué de façon impersonnelle, *il me faut ce livre* signifiait donc "il me manque ce livre", écrit Georges Gougenheim dans *Les Mots français* (1962) ; puis le sens est devenu "ce livre m'est nécessaire, j'ai besoin de ce livre".

Comment: La réponse est contenue dans la citation : « Falloir, quant à lui, n'est autre que la réfection de faillir (pris au sens de « faire défaut, manquer » ». Un des premiers sens de faillir c'est manquer. https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/faillir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme indiqué dans votre citation :

> "Il me faut ceci"

avait originellement le sens de :

> "ceci me fait défaut, me manque"

ce qui inclut donc déjà le besoin, la nécessité, contrairement à un simple :

> "je n'ai pas ceci (mais ça ne manque pas forcément)"

Pour reprendre votre exemple, un aveugle n'a *a priori* pas besoin d'une voiture, on ne dira donc pas qu'elle lui manque (sauf peut-être rétrospectivement pour quelqu'un ayant perdu la vue).